# Why is sympy unable to compute limit of Dirac delta?

Tags: python, sympy, limit

I'm using the sympy function *limit* to compute values of functions (I'm actually only interested in the sign) which allow me to deal with Indeterminate form.

The last function tested lead to compute the limit of a Dirac delta but python never managed to find a value and got stuck on this instruction.

I try on a simplified script and the same issue arise. This is the script:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x', real=True)
print(limit(DiracDelta(x), x, -1))
```

The expected answer being 0 since
lim (x -> -1) δ(x)=0

Can you tell me why python is unable to compute this limit ?

Is there a way to avoid this issue ?

Comment: I guess this is a bug in SymPy 1.8. The latest SymPy master gives 0 quickly. Maybe try the current master branch?